# Excel IF formula with 7 different possible variables

Tags: excel, formula

first time here!

I'm looking to return a value if a cell contains any of 7 different variables.

As it stands, the formula is as follows:

=IF(H13=1, "C", if(H13=4, "C", if(H13=7, "C", if(H13=10, "C", if(H13=13, "C", if(H13=16, "C", if(H13=19, "C")))))))

It works, but the formula is already unnecessarily long. And this would be combined with five others like it as part of one giant formula. I'm sure there's a way to consolidate. I've tried if(or) but that only allows for two variables. How would I create a formula that allows seven variables?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can OR them all together.

```
=IF(OR(H13=1,H13=4,H13=7,H13=10,H13=13,H13=16,H13=19),"C")
```

The other method is using an array formula:

```
=IF(OR(EXACT(H13,L5:L11)),"C")
```

With L5:L11 being `{1,4,7,10,13,16,19}`

You can read about that using the [Excel docs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/compare-cell-contents-HP003056130.aspx#BMcompare_one_value_to_a_list_of_values)

The first one is simpler to maintain, the second one is more flexible.

Comment: +1 for the OR(EXACT technique.  You don't need EXACT since you're comparing numbers to numbers: {=IF(OR(H13=L5:L11),"C")}.  You can avoid using extra cells and avoid entering it as an array formula like this:  =IF(OR(H13={1,4,7,10,13,16,19}),"C")

Answer (score 0):

In your example, "C" is returned if H13 modulus 3 is 1 *and* H13 is less than 20:

```
=IF(AND(MOD(H13,3)=1,H13<20),"C","")
```

The following method would work whether the "C"s were evenly distributed or not:

```
=MID("C  C  C  C  C  C  C",H13,1)
```

If other values for H13 should return a single letter, you could include them in the string:

```
=MID("CABCDFCWECZECABCERC",H13,1)
```

Leave gaps if some values of H13 should return a blank.

Another method, inspired by @Compass's post, is to use `OR` in this manner:

```
=IF(OR(H13={1,4,7,10,13,16,19}),"C")
```

Note that you *don't* need to enter this as an array formula.